# What does @SingleValueResult do?

Tags: java, jdbi

What does [`@SingleValueResult`](http://jdbi.org/apidocs/org/skife/jdbi/v2/sqlobject/customizers/SingleValueResult.html) do? Does it impose the constraint 'single value result'?

Full name: `org.skife.jdbi.v2.sqlobject.customizers.SingleValueResult`

Here are some links about it:

- https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/jdbi/tQge_FNUoiw
- https://news.ycombinator.com/item?id=8134591

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, it doesn't.

Instead it just provides some more type information for `Optional` or `Maybe` return types.

When JDBI recognizes that only a single row will be needed from the database, it will tell the database that only one row will be needed (see `addStatementCustomizer(StatementCustomizers.MAX_ROW_ONE)` in the `Query` class).

This will let the database optimize the returned data. But your Java application will never know if there was ever a second row.